# Silverlight Validation Problem

Tags: silverlight, validation

I have a Silverlight control which has a ListBox showing a series of email addresses. The data source is an ObservableCollection of strings (one per email) in the ViewModel. Simple enough!

I wanted to allow in-place editing of the list, by changing the data template from a TextBlock to a TextBox, with a two-way binding.

The problem is this: **How do I validate the user edit is a valid email address?**

I don't want to save the bound text to the list unless it's valid. I can't throw an exception as it's bound to a string, so there's no Set method to modify.

The only solution I can think of is to create a dummy class with a single Email property just so I can validate the value. I can't believe that's the best way.

Comment: What is the __Exact__ type that the ListBox is binding to?

Comment: The binding is a ListBox with the DataContext set to {Binding Path=EmailList}

EmailList is:
public ObservableCollection<string> EmailList { get; set; }

The ListBox template has a single TextBound bound to {Binding}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you've got bigger problems than just the validation.  You can't use TwoWay binding when the source object is a string.

It does make some sense to create an `AddressEntry` class that has an `EmailAddress` string property.  That way you can make two way binding work and it gives you somewhere to write your validation.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. It's taking me (asp.net developer) a while to unthink how to write UI code with Silverlight.